# Need help building MySQL Query - Dynamic Data

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a legacy table `Prop` that depending on the sign of `value` will tell whether to reference `PropLong` or `PropShort` tables.  To be clear if `Prop.value > 0` look to `PropShort` else `PropLong`.

Now I want to build a dynamic query based on the ultimate value.  I am not sure how to do this.  I already have a query (feel free to comment on this too) that will pull the final value back (into `str_value` but I don't know how to modify it such that I can further extend my query on `str_value`.

```
SELECT *, 
   IFNULL(PropShort.str, PropLong.str) AS str_value FROM Prop 
   LEFT JOIN PropShort ON sid=Prop.value 
   LEFT JOIN PropLong ON lid=-Prop.value
```

Now where does `WHERE PropShort.str=%s OR PropLong.str=%s` come into this?  I am particularly concerned in OR'ing multiple queries (i.e `WHERE PropShort.str=%s OR PropLong.str=%s OR behavior="foo"`)

Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE `Prop` (
  `propId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `behavior` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY `propId` (`propId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `PropLong` (
  `lid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `str` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `PropShort` (
  `sid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `str` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends... but MIGHT be

```
SELECT *, 
      IFNULL(PropShort.str, PropLong.str) AS str_value 
   FROM 
      Prop 
         LEFT JOIN PropShort 
            ON sid=Prop.value 
            AND PropShort.str=%s 
         LEFT JOIN PropLong 
            ON lid=-Prop.value
           AND PropLong.str=%s
```

Now this will still keep your "Prop" table the primary, but will only join up to the respective other tables based on BOTH their respective conditions.  So you could have a PropShort by the ID, but not match the .str, yet have a valid PropLONG match the ID AND have the proper .str to get what you are looking for.

Comment: This would work if the only constraint was this.  Unfortunately it's not. I'll clarify this in my post.

Comment: @rh0dium, So... Is your FIRST consideration that of (either prop short/long has a str of %s) OR (the prop can behavior='foo'), THEN grab all those records that qualify?  Completely different, and showing some sample data for this and future would help clarify that.

Comment: No - having either prop short/long is a secondary consideration.  Thank you so much you pointed questions are helping me.  I'm not there yet but I see where you are going